# Getting 2 divs to perfectly divide the page in 1/2 using exact pixelage

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to get 2 divs to perfectly divide a page. My HTML logic is as follows.

- The total width of an element is its `width` plus twice the size of its `border-size`
- The outer div is 700 pixels wide and has no padding
- Therefore, I can make a perfect subdivision with 2 inner `div`s by making them have `display: inline; width: 348px; border: 1px;` They will be squashed up right next to each other and take up the entire width of the outer div.

But for some reason this isn't working. Please cleanse me of my sins.

Link: http://jaminweb.com/practice.html

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>practice page</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .main-content
            {
                border: 1px dashed black;
                padding: 0px;
                width: 700px;
            }
            .left-side
            {
                border: 1px dashed blue;
                margin: 0px;
                float: left;
                width: 348px;
                height: 900px;
                display: inline;
            }
            .right-side
            {
                border: 1px dashed red;
                margin: 0px;
                float: right;
                width: 348px;
                height: 900px;
                display: inline;
            }
        </style>
    </head>  
    <body>
        <div class="main-content">
            <div class="left-side">
                <p>Here's the left side.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="right-side">
                <p>And here's the right side</p>
            </div>
        </div>       
    </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Why not just `width: 50%`?

Comment: It's doing exactly what you told it to do. Are you trying to center the .main-content in the center of the page?

Comment: it's working exactly as you want, not getting your question at all

Answer (score -2):

You could also set the two inner div's to `width: 50%;` if you use `box-sizing: border-box;`. Then you dont have to think about border-sizes, and it's a more flexible structure.

Comment: I agree with using 50% width, but since he says he is going for "exact pixelage", I think he is trying to grasp the concept of the box model and how borders and widths correlate to the overall width of an element. I wasn't the one that down voted you though.

Comment: He/she could have done this in many ways, the way he is using is correct, so this is not an answer, but a comment

Comment: @bboysupaman my thought: maybe its enaugh for him/her to have the "exact pixelage" on the outer container.

Comment: @Fabio yeah.. i'm not allowed to comment. i was one point away from the reputation-score thats needed for comments. ..this sucks.

Comment: @DerZyklop Well, now you're further away! You're not allowed to because the powers that be don't intend you to. So why do you think posting it as an answer is appropriate? Focus on good answers that will net you the sufficient rep instead. :)